# How to pass a parameter to where in chained Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm Having trouble with chaining multiple relationships in Laravel when adding a where clause to the relationship:

**User Model:** One to many Relationship to UserProfiles

columns: id, username, email, current_region

```
class User
{
 public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class)->where('region_code',$this->current_region);

    }
}
```

**Note:**  I am using hasOne to get a single record in this case while relationship is oneToMany

**UserProfile Model:**

columns: name, number, user_id, region_code

**Attachment Model:**

columns: file, name, user_id, region_code

```
class Attachment
{
 public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I need to access userProfle from attachment model.

```
attachment->user->userprofile; // returns null because $this->current_region is not accessible as the context for user model is not available yet
```

however I can access the userProfile from User model directly

```
$user->userProfile // return expected response;
```

How can I pass the parameter to the User model from Attachment Model or is there a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly eager load nested relationships as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$attachments = App\attachment::with('owner.profile')->get();
```

Then you should be able to access the profile like so

```
$profile = $attachment->owner->profile;
```